# validate_pin exercise—I don’t get where I'm wrong or if I'm the good track

Tags: python

I'm trying to run this validate_pin code from [Codewars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codewars) in Python.

```
def validate_pin(atm):
    if len(atm) != 4 and len(atm) != 6:
        for i in atm:
            if i not in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']:
                return False
                break
            else:
                return True
```

Is it is OK or not?

Comment: Can you share example of not working case that should work ?

Comment: Do you understand what `return` does?

Comment: If the pin is neither 4 nor 6 characters long, this function doesn't return anything.  Also, the inner `for` loop always does a `return`, so the loop will only run one time.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you for this comment.. Now I get it, thank you.

Comment: @azro this is a problem from codewars my code it wasnt right if I tried something like "a203" it says True

Comment: yes I do but I took a time before going bed yesterday to read some articles about it  eg : (https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-return/#:~:text=The%20return%20keyword%20in%20Python,read%20them%20throughout%20your%20code.) @PM77-1

Answer (score 1):

The correct specification is

> ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.

So your first `if` is wrong. You may accept only 4 or 6-length PINs, not other sizes. Then in your loop, finding a valid digit doesn't make the PIN valid. You need to check all characters to be able to be sure, so wait the end.

```
def validate_pin(atm):
    if len(atm) != 4 and len(atm) != 6:
        return False
    for i in atm:
        if not i.isdigit():
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I tried to use online if and else statement with out any built in function, thank you btw really appreciated. (Y) staysafe